Node.js Server Error: EADDRINUSE - Address Already in Use Despite Terminating Process
After 1st time successfully started server and when I again start my server then I'm encountering an issue with my Node.js server where I receive the following error message:
node:events:496
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8000
at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1897:16)
at listenInCluster (node:net:1945:12)
at Server.listen (node:net:2037:7)
at Function.listen (/home/sujal/Practise/Website/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:635:24)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/sujal/Practise/Website/app.js:13:5)

I've tried to resolve this issue by terminating the Node.js process associated with my application using the PID obtained from ps aux and kill command. However, even after terminating the process, the error persists.
I've also attempted to resolve the issue by trying different Node.js versions using npm, but the problem remains unresolved. Currently, I'm using Node.js v20.12.2.
Could anyone provide guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve this error? What could be causing the Node.js server to remain in use despite terminating the process? Are there any additional steps I should take to identify and stop the process causing this issue?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!
